# htaccess negating REQUEST_URI not working

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to deny access from specific IP Address except subdomain URL using htaccess. In other words if client with ip address 192.168.0.10 try to access URL other than /news.* i want to return Response:403.

I'm expecting my htaccess file to be something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^192\.168\.0\.10
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/news.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [R=403,L]
```

But when i access any url(even **/news**) it returns 403.
Without negating REQUEST_URI(like below), it works as expected.(only /news.* requests return 403, but i want opposite)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/news.*$ [NC]
```

Where am i making mistake ?

Comment: Where is your htaccess located?

Comment: @starkeen `/var/www/html/public/.htaccess`

Comment: Do you have any other htaccess in /news ?

Comment: @starkeen nope, it's actually laravel project

Comment: Look for [logging actions](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging).

Comment: Did you try to add an `=` sign in front of the IP? All the `RewriteCond` involving `%{REMOTE_ADDR}` examples I could find for Apache 2.2 and 2.4 use it. See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/access.html
Unless you use Apache 2.0, in this case it looks like the correct syntax. If the syntax is incorrect, it might always apply the rule because the conds are invalid.